# How can I call a distinct route with a middleware and without a middleware in Node.Js , Express, Handlebars, Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

I have two route.
One is

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{

  res.render('home/index')
})
```

another one is

```
router.get('/', checklogin, (req,res)=>{

  res.render('home/index',{
  email: req.email,
  name: req.username,
  role: req.role
})
})
```

Here is my checklogin middleware

```
const checklogin = (req, res, next) =>{
const token = req.cookies.ntoken;
  try{
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
     const {username, email, role} = decoded;
     req.username = username;
     req.email = email;
     req.role = role;
     next();
  }
  catch (err){
    console.log(err);
    next("Invalid Token")
    next()
  }

}

module.exports = checklogin;
```

I want to redirect to the router.get('/', checklogin, (req,res)=>{}) route after login. And show the logged-in user's name on the handlebars page. I have 2 user types; admin and user. Users can log in and do some work crud operation and admin also will do the same.
I have tried to redirect to the router.get('/', checklogin, (req,res)=>{}) route after login.

I have tried to redirect to router.get('/', checklogin, (req,res)=>{}) route after login.

Here is my login route

```
 router.post('/login', (req, res) => {


    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
      res.render('auth/login',{
        error_msg: 'Please Give Email And Password',
        layout: false
    })
    }
    else {
      User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } })
        .then(user => {
          if (!user) {
            res.render('auth/login',{
                error_msg: 'This Email Is Not Registered',
                layout: false
            })
          } else {
  
                    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (isMatch) {
                        const token = jwt.sign({
                            username: user.name,
                            email: user.email,
                            role: user.role
                        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
                            expiresIn: '1h'
                        });
                       
                        res.cookie('ntoken', token,{
                            httpOnly:true
                        })
                        res.redirect('/');
                      

                    }
                    else {
                        res.render('auth/login',{
                            error_msg: 'Invalid Password',
                            layout: false
                        })
                    }

                });
            }

        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  
    }
  
  })
```

I have another routes
In admin.js
`router.get("/dashboard", checklogin, async (req, res) => {})`
In user.js
`router.get("/dashboard", checlogin, async (req, res) => {})`

In app.js file

```
const home = require('./routes/home/home');
const admin = require('./routes/admin/admin');
const user = require('./routes/user/user');
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/', home);
app.use('/admin', admin);
```

I tried this . But I am not getting my desired output in handlebars page..

Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

You could make a different middleware for parsing the token that just sets the `req` user properties and always continues routing.

```
const parselogin = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(req.cookies.ntoken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        const { username, email, role } = decoded;
        req.username = username;
        req.email = email;
        req.role = role;
    } finally {
        next();
    }
}
```

Then, you can use just this one route for both the logged in and not logged in case:

```
router.get('/', parselogin, (req, res) => {
    res.render('home/index', {
        email: req.email,
        name: req.username,
        role: req.role
    });
});
```

In the not logged in case, `req.email`, `req.username` and `req.role` will be `undefined` so as long as your template handles that fine, it should work.